# how to load class file using other computer

Tags: java, exception, malformedurlexception

Hello i am trying to access a java class file from other computer using LAN wire.
I have to load Tester class file from ip 192.168.0.1 from user folder!! Please Help to how can i do this and my code describe below.

```
import java.net.*;
public class MyLoader {
   public static void main (String argv[]) throws Exception {


      URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("\\192.168.0.1\\user") });//ip of other computer  where from  user folder i use Tester class

      // Load class from class loader. argv[0] is the name of the class to be loaded
      Class c = loader.loadClass (argv[0]);

      // Create an instance of the class just loaded
      Object o = c.newInstance();

  }
}
```

at run time i use [java MyLoader Tester].
Here my tester java file

```
public class Tester {

public Tester () {
      System.out.println ("Hello there");
   }

   public static void main(String argv[]) {
     System.out.println("Network Class Loaders");
   }
}
```

I got this exception error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: \192.168
.0.1\user
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at MyLoader.main(MyLoader.java:7)
```

Comment: (Not tested) As the exception suggests, try using a scheme in the URL, say, `file://192.168.0.1/user`

Answer (score 2):

`\192.168.0.1\user` isn't a valid URL, as the exception says. A URL requires a protocol (file, http, https etc) so that the system knows how to access the resources.

As Alexander suggested, try `file://192.168.0.1/user` - also try this from your browser to see if this folder is actually accessible via a `file://` URL.

Is it just a shared folder you are trying to access, or is the file being made available by a web server on the other machine (in which case use the `http` protocol)?

Comment: I think you need some extra `/` or \ . I would Try: `new URL("file://\\\\192.168.0.1\\user")`

Comment: I wasn't intending it to be Java syntax (i.e. escaped) as that's always rather unreadable - but you are correct that it would need escaping within the code.